# Extract html div class using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, python-3.6

I want to get '8.0' from the HTML below:

```
<div class="js-otelpuani" style="float: left;"> ==$0
 "8.0"
 <span class="greyish" style="font-size:13px; font-
 family:arial;"> /10</span>
 ::after
</div>
```

I have tried the code below to extract '8.0' inside div class = 'js-otelpuani', but it seems it did not work;

```
import urllib
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pyodbc

headers = {
"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5)",
"accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
"accept-charset": "cp1254,ISO-8859-9,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3",
"accept-encoding": "gzip,deflate,sdch",
"accept-language": "tr,tr-TR,en-US,en;q=0.8",
}
r = requests.get('https://www.otelz.com/otel/elvin-deluxehotel#.WkDIBd9l_IU', headers=headers)
if r.status_code != 200:
    print("request denied")
else:
    print("ok")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text) 
    score = soup.find('div',attrs={'class': 'js-otelpuani'})
    print(score)
```

I get these as output but unfortunately I could not get '8.0' value that I want to extract;

```
ok
<div class="js-otelpuani" style="float: left;">
<span id="comRatingValue">.0</span>
<span class="greyish" style="font-size: 13px; font-family: arial;">
/
<span itemprop="bestRating">10</span></span>
<span id="comRatingCount" itemprop="ratingCount" style="display: 
none;">0</span>
<span id="comReviewCount" itemprop="reviewCount" style="display: 
none;">0</span>
</div>
```

I will be grateful for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you examine the HTML code of the page and search for the `js-otelpuani`, you would notice that is also used inside a `script` tag and, if you follow the logic of that script, you would see that the *rating itself is formed from a separate query to the `GeneralPartial/Degerlendirmeler/8974` endpoint* where `8974` is a hotel id.

Let's simulate this exact logic in your script - first extracting the hotel id, making a separate request and extracting the rating value:

```
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


headers = {
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5)",
    "accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
    "accept-charset": "cp1254,ISO-8859-9,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3",
    "accept-encoding": "gzip,deflate,sdch",
    "accept-language": "tr,tr-TR,en-US,en;q=0.8",
}

with requests.Session() as session:
    session.headers = headers

    r = session.get('https://www.otelz.com/otel/elvin-deluxehotel#.WkDIBd9l_IU', headers=headers)
    if r.status_code != 200:
        print("request denied")
    else:
        print("ok")
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")

        # get the hotel id
        hotel_id = soup.find(attrs={"data-hotelid": True})["data-hotelid"]

        # go for the hotel rating
        response = session.get("https://www.otelz.com/GeneralPartial/Degerlendirmeler/{hotel_id}".format(hotel_id=hotel_id))
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

        rating_value = soup.find(attrs={'data-rating-value': True})['data-rating-value']
        print(rating_value)
```

Prints:

```
8.0
```

Answer (score 2):

you should probably use something like this :

```
soup.find('div', {'class' :'js-otelpuani'}).text
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to go for selenium then the data you are after can be parsed very easily like below:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium  import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.otelz.com/otel/elvin-deluxehotel#.WkDf39KWa1t')
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"lxml")
for item in soup.select('.js-otelpuani'):
    [elem.extract() for elem in soup("span")]
    print(item.text)
driver.quit()
```

Output:

```
8.0
```